# Android: How to call JS function from Webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I know we can call js function from Webview. like this
`webview.loadUrl("javascript:functionName('param')");`

But in case function is like below js object.functionName.

```
 pap.changeLanguage = function(a, n) { $("body").addClass("lang-loading"), setParameterByName("language", a + "-" +Country),initDDBViewerLang()}
```

Note: We can't change anything from js/html side. we need handle from app side only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve, we can call js function with js object name dot function name

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:pap.changeLanguage('" + value0 + "','"+value1+"')");
```